# WinRE password reset, or a similar method?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, user-accounts, administrator

As it happens, I lost the password to my admin account on win7. It was the only admin account on the machine, so logging in with another account isn't an option.

Now, normally this would't be an issue: I'll either use a livecd or the sethc backdoor. Having no livecd at hand (just when I need it), I go into the recovery option on boot, and discover there is a password set. Ugh.

As there is no accessible admin account, I can't even remove it through the registry. Is there another way to get an elevated console like through WinRE, or remove the WinRE password requirement?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake - completely forgot Startup Repair doesn't use WinRE access settings. Just got into that.
Answer to my original question: Startup Repair can be used to get an elevated command prompt